# Unable to debug AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to debug [this code](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-todomvc-starter/blob/master/src/app/services/services.js#L5).

But I'm unable do that. I can debug controllers for example  (i suppose it works when i open page in browser just because es6 already translated in es5 and mappings are created), but i can't step here (because mappings is not generated?).

Maybe I'm do something wrong and it is possible, research this code with debugger?

Answer (score 0):

If code is running in the browser, then it's debuggable.

If you can't debug it, then:

1. Either, you haven't set and triggered breakpoints correctly.
2. Or, it's not actually running.

The code may not be running at all if you haven't transpiled it (ES6 --> ES5.)

You may need to run `npm install` and/or `bower install` etc in the project to get the `devDependencies`, and then follow the build instructions.

EDIT: if you can debug controllers but not services, then the problem is likely just that you aren't calling any service code - you need to do something in the application to trigger that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use alert check which line is executing after which line in js. and for the angular, you can use `console.log()` function or `alert()` in angular too. I use these two function to check which line is giving an error.
like:

```
line1
line2    alert("Up to line no 2 it's running well")
line3 
line4    alert("Up to line no 4 it's running well")
```

if `alert("Up to line no 4 it's running well")` not displayed on your screen means there is a problem in line no 3.